# Building an ActiveRecord relation without having it execute the query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am trying to build a query as follows:

```
rel = article.where(version: 'some_version')
             .joins(:categories)
             .merge(Category.where(:uuid => 'some_cat_uuid'))

articles = rel.where(published: true).limit(10)
# etc.
```

The problem is the first query seems to execute no matter what I do. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Umm, you're second variable `articles` uses your first variable `rel`. Of course it's going to execute that query every time!

Comment: @n_i_c_k how so?  You can chain arel queries like this just fine.  I suspect the query execution happens because of that `.merge`...

Comment: Scratch that, `.merge` shouldn't execute the query.  Are you doing this in the console?

Comment: @n_i_c_k yes it was in the console. I'll try from a rake task

Comment: @n_i_c_k sorry for the late reply. I tried it using a rake task and it looks like your hunch is correct. From a rake task is appears to work as expected. If you want to turn you comment into an answer I'll mark it correct. Thanks

Comment: rainkinz, not me. I think you meant @nzifnab. Sorry for the incorrect comment, I didn't realize that was possible.

Comment: Oops, sorry you're right. @nzifnab if you want to convert your comment to an answer I'll mark it correct. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

When you run commands in the console, it automatically adds something similar to `.inspect` at the end to display the results of the command.  For instance (this is in my app that I'm working on right now):

```
irb(main):061:0> Job.where(id: 251000)
  Job Load (3.8ms)  SELECT "jobs".* FROM "jobs" WHERE "jobs"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND "jobs"."id" = 251000
=> [#<Job id: 251000, {...}>]
```

So, your first line of code is just fine and would not normally execute the query, but since you were running it in the console it executes immediately so that it can display the results for you.

One way to get around this is to add `; nil` to the end of the command, that way the console won't attempt to display the results (it'll just display nil as the result of that line.  IE:

```
irb(main):062:0> Job.where(id: 251000); nil
=> nil
```

Doing it this way you should be able to do what you were expecting (delay execution of the query until you actually need the results):

```
rel = article.where(version: 'some_version')
             .joins(:categories)
             .merge(Category.where(:uuid => 'some_cat_uuid')); nil

articles = rel.where(published: true).limit(10); nil
```

Then you can execute the query by using `articles.all` (in Rails 3) or `articles.to_a` (in Rails 4)

Of course if you then move this code to a rake task or model or something you can drop those `; nil` bits because they look a little cluttered and would be useless at that point.

Another point of contention for the console might be that it'll see that `.where() {NEWLINE}` and execute the query at that point, I tend to put the dot on the previous line to remove any ambiguity of where my command is ending:

```
rel = article.where(version: 'some_version').
             joins(:categories).
             merge(Category.where(:uuid => 'some_cat_uuid')); nil
```

Comment: It seems that this only works with [ActiveRecord::QueryMethods](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html) (`where`, `joins`, `group`, etc.). It does NOT work with [ActiveRecord::FinderMethods](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html) (`first`, `find`, `find_by`, etc.). The `FinderMethods` will immediately execute the query regardless of the `; nil` syntax.

Comment: @Crazydog yes, but that is because those are not lazy-loaded methods. Those methods load immediately no matter where they're run from.

Comment: Noice one dude!